# PHP storing stringed JSON diff than JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, json

Via JavaScript I'm able to store a cookie with JSON.stringify(), which stores a cookie directly as I.e.

```
'[{"n":"50fb0d0cc1277d182f000002","q":2},{"n":"50fb0d09c1277d182f000001","q":1},{"n":"50fb0d06c1277d182f000000","q":1}]
```

I'm now passing this through a rest API, where the other endpoint receives then needs to re-corporate into the same cookie key and value on the server end.  I do this using PHP's set cookie.  I'm able to pass through the vars correctly, however when setting cookie with the JSON value it keeps becoming urldecoded, I'm storing it as a straight string and it still becomes I.e:

> %5B%7B%22n%22%3A%2250fb0d9dc1277d1b2f000003%22%2C%22q%22%3A3%7D%5D

Any ideas? why this is storing as a decoded value?

Comment: Keep in mind that I have tried urldecode / jsondecode then back into jsonencode.

Comment: Give us some code, please.

Comment: Uh, I mean it's basic javascript set cookie and php set cookie functions...  Those are standards.  The question is, how do you get PHP to store JSON string directly into a cookie without url-decoding it, just like JavaScript's JSON.stringify function.

Comment: But this is urlencoded. What happens when you urldecode it with php?

Comment: Roy, it's still stored as decoded URL.

Comment: @MichaelMikhjian urldecode on that string doesn`t change it? Please, create brief test code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out.  PHP setcookie by default encodes value, need to use setrawcookie!

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setrawcookie.php